# Lightning Design System is note getting displayed in IE11

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, internet-explorer

I am using Lightning Design System for Css. I works well in Mozilla and chrome,But the icons getting disappeared in IE11.

**Static Resource**

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.RForce_LightningDesign_STR, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css')}"/>
```

**Code**

```
<td>
                                <a href="#" >
                                    <svg aria-hidden="true" style="height:40px;width:20px;position:absolute;" class="">
                                        <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.RForce_LightningDesign_STR,'/assets/icons/action-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#flow')}"></use>
                                    </svg>
                                </a>

                                <a href="#" >
                                    <svg aria-hidden="true" width="40" height="20" position="absolute" class="">
                                        <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.RForce_LightningDesign_STR,'/assets/icons/action-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#remove')}"></use>
                                    </svg>
                                </a>
                            </td>
```

Please help me resolve this problem in IE11.

Comment: See if this post might help explain the issue your facing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516712/svg-use-tag-with-external-reference-in-ie-11

Answer (score 1):

SFDC docs [says](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=getstart_browsers_sfx.htm&language=en_US):

Lightning Experience is supported with Apple® Safari® version 8.x and 9.x on Mac OS X and Microsoft® Edge for Windows® 10. The most recent stable versions of Mozilla® Firefox® and Google Chrome™ are also supported. **If you’re using Microsoft® Internet Explorer® versions 9–11, you’re redirected to Salesforce Classic. There are some limitations.**

So basically it has limited supported which is going to be discontinue in December 16, 2017

**https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Retirement-of-Support-for-Microsoft-Internet-Explorer-version-11-with-Lightning-Experience**